# PHP file does not return text in .responseText

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I have to files. A javascript file that is making an AJAX request to a PHP file that is suppose to return JSON. I have tested the PHP file with a print statment and there is definetly JSON being made. However in javascript the request.responseText is empty.

Javascript:

```
var mCurrentIndex = 0;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var mImages = [];
var json;
var url = "fiveMostRecent.php";
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send();
request.onreadystatechange = function(e)
{
    if(request.readyState == 4 || request.readyState == 2){
        console.log(request.responseText);
        json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(json);
        for(var x = 0; x < json.length; x++){
            var gImage = new GalleryImage();
            gImage.title = json[x].title;
            gImage.price = json[x].price;
            gImage.description = json[x].description;
            gImage.img = new Image();
            gImage.img.src = json.images[x].imgPath;
            makeGalleryImageOnloadCallback(gImage);
            mImages.push(gImage);
        }
    }
    console.log(mImages);
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "listAdmin", "hermes");
if(!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("GregsList", $con)
    or die("Unable to select database:" . mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT title, description, price FROM Listings ORDER BY dateListed DESC LIMIT 5";

$result = mysql_query($query);

#converts to json
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
        $rows[] = $r;
}

#print json_encode($rows);
return json_encode($rows);

?>
```

Comment: Why did you comment out the `print` statement? That's the correct way to send the results to the client.

Comment: how about changing this line return json_encode($rows); to return json_encode(array("$rows"=>$rows));

Comment: Set up the `onreadystatechange` handler before sending the request - just move `request.send()` to the bottom of the javascript snippet.

Comment: `request.readyState == 2` Who taught you that? That is not right!

Comment: give me a minute to try all of these

Comment: using the print statement instead of return solved the problem thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `echo json_encode($rows);` instead of  `return json_encode($rows);`